# Not get push notifications from Cloud Messaging Google when the application is terminated

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, messaging

I have configured the server with Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1).
I have made a function so that it shows a notification after 5 seconds when pressing the notification icon button, I close the application before the 5 seconds pass, the notification does not appear when the application is closed but it does appear when the app is in the background.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final _credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "proyecto-,
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key":
      "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"
});

Future<String> getAccessToken() async {
  try {
    final client = http.Client();
    final AccessCredentials credentials =
        await obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(_credentials,
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'], client);

    final accessToken = credentials.accessToken.data;
    client.close();
    return accessToken;
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error obteniendo el token de acceso: $e");
    throw e;
  }
}

Future<void> sendPushNotification(
    String token, String title, String body) async {
  try {
    const String sendUrl =
        'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/proyecto-chatgpt-84b99/messages:send';
    final String accessToken = await getAccessToken();

    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(sendUrl),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: json.encode({
        'message': {
          'token': token,
          'notification': {
            'title': title,
            'body': body,
          },
          'android': {
            'priority': 'high',
          },
        },
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to send notification: ${response.body}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error sending the notification: $e");
    throw e;
  }
}

Future<void> sendPushNotificationToUser(
    String userId, String title, String body) async {
  try {
    // Obtiene el token FCM del usuario desde Firestore
    final docSnapshot = await _firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).get();

    if (docSnapshot.exists && docSnapshot.data()?['fcmToken'] != null) {
      String userToken = docSnapshot.data()?['fcmToken'];
      await sendPushNotification(userToken, title, body);
    } else {
      print("Token FCM no encontrado para el usuario: $userId");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error enviando la notificación: $e");
    throw e;
  }
}
```

I have used two functions sendPushNotification and sendPushNotificationToUser. In both cases it doesn't work. The first function is configured to show notifications using the service account key. In the second function use the other function + the FCM token generated from main.dart:

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/authentication/auth_google.dart';
import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/fcm/fcm_helper.dart';
import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/notifications/schedule_notifications.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
// import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
//import 'package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/providers/chats_provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

//import 'package:chatgpt_project/src/providers/models_provider.dart';
//import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter_native_timezone/flutter_native_timezone.dart';

final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  //tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation('America/Lima'));

  // Establecer la zona horaria local del dispositivo
  final String timeZoneName = await FlutterNativeTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
  tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));

  //FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  // Usa la localización actual del dispositivo
  //await initializeDateFormatting();

  //DateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);

  // Cargar las variables de entorno
  // Cargar las variables de entorno
  //await dotenv.load(fileName: ".env");

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  await initializeDateFormatting('es_ES', null);
  //FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;

  // Configuración del canal de notificación
  // const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  //   'high_priority_channel', // id
  //   'High Priority Notifications', // title
  //   importance: Importance.high,
  //   playSound: true,
  //   showBadge: true,
  // );
  // final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  //     FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  // await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  //     .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
  //         AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
  //     ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  // Inicializa Firebase Messaging
  _configureFirebaseListeners();

  final CallbackHandle callback =
      PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle(callbackDispatcher)!;
  final int callbackHandle = callback.toRawHandle();
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await prefs.setInt('callback_handle', callbackHandle);

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ChatProvider()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

Future<void> updateTokenToFirestore(String token) async {
  // Obtiene el userId del usuario autenticado
  String? currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

  if (currentUserId != null) {
    final docRef = _firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUserId);
    final docSnapshot = await docRef.get();

    if (docSnapshot.exists) {
      await docRef.update({'fcmToken': token});
    } else {
      // Considera la posibilidad de crear un nuevo documento si no existe.
      // Puedes agregar más campos si es necesario.
      await docRef.set({
        'fcmToken': token,
        // 'otrosCampos': 'otrosValores',
      });
    }
  }
}

void _configureFirebaseListeners() async {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  // Obtener y manejar el token de FCM
  _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String? token) {
    assert(token != null);
    print("Token de FCM: $token");
    updateTokenToFirestore(token!);
  });

  // Escuchar cambios en el token
  _firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((String token) {
    print("Token de FCM actualizado: $token");
    updateTokenToFirestore(token);
  });

  _firebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {
    if (message != null) {
      // Maneja la notificación causada por un 'tap' en la notificación
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    // Maneja la notificación cuando la aplicación está en primer plano
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    // Maneja la notificación causada por un 'tap' en la notificación
  });
}

void fetchMedicinesFromBoot(List<String> args) async {
  // Aquí puedes invocar fetchMedicines con el userId que necesites.
  String? userId =
      await getUserId(); // Aquí deberías implementar la función getUserId si aún no lo has hecho.
  if (userId != null) {
    fetchMedicines(userId);
  }
}

void callbackDispatcher() {
  const MethodChannel _backgroundChannel =
      MethodChannel('com.example.chatgpt_project/background_channel');
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  _backgroundChannel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
    if (call.method == 'fetchMedicinesFromBoot') {
      fetchMedicinesFromBoot([]);
    }
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key})
      : super(
            key:
                key); //CON ANALYTICS: const MyApp({Key? key, required this.analytics}) : super(key: key);

  //final FirebaseAnalytics analytics;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: Routes.loading,
      routes: Routes.routes,
      //navigatorObservers: [
      // FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
      //],
    );
  }
}
```

That is the button to test notifications, the second function is used. What's more, I have tried with the two functions of fcm_helpder.dart, neither of them work when the app is terminated but they do show in the background:

```
child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications,
                  color: Colors.white, size: 33.0),
              onPressed: () async {
                try {
                  // Obtiene el userId del usuario autenticado
                  String? currentUserId =
                      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;

                  if (currentUserId != null) {
                    print('Preparando para enviar notificación...');

                    // Espera 5 segundos antes de enviar la notificación
                    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));

                    // Envia una notificación de prueba usando el userId
                    await sendPushNotificationToUser(
                        currentUserId,
                        'Notificación de prueba',
                        'Esta es una notificación de prueba');

                    print('Notificación enviada exitosamente.');
                  } else {
                    print('No hay usuario autenticado.');
                  }
                } catch (e) {
                  print("Error al intentar enviar notificación de prueba: $e");
                }
              },
            ),
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chatgpt_project">

   <!-- Permiso para acceder a Internet -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

   <!-- Permisos para las notificaciones -->
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

   <application
        android:label="chatgpt_project"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <!-- Receiver for handling boot completed to restore scheduled notifications after a reboot -->
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <!-- BootReceiver to handle re-scheduling notifications after device reboot -->
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Configuración para el canal de notificaciones de Firebase -->
        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="high_priority_channel" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I would greatly appreciate the support... today for me tomorrow for you

I need to show google cloud messaging push notifications when the application is terminated

Comment: await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)); <= This will not work if the application is killed from the background. You will need to use backend server to perform this.

Comment: Try uncommenting this line : FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler)

Comment: This function is used to recieve notification when your app is in background or terminated state.